# How to create an elegant guard / return statement in Swift that gives output?

Tags: ios, swift, return, guard

For example, this works:

```
guard condition == true else { return }
```

Which is fine, but creates a silent failure. What would be nice is to have a static function that could output feedback whilst also returning. Something like:

```
guard condition == true else { stop("condition was false") }
```

Am I living in dreamland here, or might this be possible?

Of course, I recognise that the following is possible:

```
guard condition == true else { 
    print("condition was false")
    return
}
```

But is boilerplate heavy and kind of ugly. I have guard statements **everywhere**, this sort of code is: 1. useful; but 2. would bulk out my code by, like, 10% minimum.

It's utopian of me I know, but I would prefer an elegant solution. Anyone?

Comment: how about `throw`ing an error simply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what your function is all about. Typically methods with `guard` statements either have no return value or return optionals.

```
func myReturn() -> String? {
    guard condition else { return nil }
}
```

if you want an analogue of stop, well, you could throw an `Error`, or even a `fatalError`

```
func myReturn() throws -> String {
    guard condition else {
         throw BadConditionError
     }
}
```

Or

```
func myReturn() -> String {
    guard condition else {
         fatalError("Bad condition")
     }
}
```

`guard` is an early exit mechanism, it prevents your program from getting into invalid state, use it accordingly. I'd also recommend reading on `defer` mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @inokey. What, though, if it is not an error? Most of my guards do not cause errors. In that case should I just shut up and accept the print;return formation?

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum In most cases you just write it as it is `guard condition else { return }`. It's actually very general rule for protecting against failable conditions and could be seen in many Swift code of many programmers.

Comment: I am aware of this @inokey, I didn't start Swift yesterday. It does seem to me to be suboptimal, is all. I guess I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to write a cute static function that returned a return

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum why violating language rules and transparency? Your custom cute solution would rise questions if a new developer would encounter your code hence you'd increase complexity where it's not necessary. Sometimes as developers we're really looking for those neat ways, but it's not always helpful for others.

Comment: I'm not here to get emotional @inokey, let's try to keep this civil. I'm not convinced having to look up one short static function qualifies as excessive complexity. This seems to be a difference of opinion rather than anything else. Occasionally I have had to spend time working out which `guard -> return` was responsible for some VC stopping working, usually more time than it would take to look up one short static function. Thank you for taking the time to respond

Comment: The thing is, some guards are errors. Fine, they can throw errors. Some guards are simply to stop unnecessary code. Fine, they can be silent. Some however qualify as neither of those, maybe some part of a VC stops working because of a a `guard`. In those cases, OK maybe `print(); return` is the answer. I don't like it, but fine, I can accept it. Good. @inokey: I'm happy to accept your answer on the basis that you apologise for your condescending tone. I am not happy to be talked at like some junior dev who just walked into your company yesterday. Thanks again for your time though, appreciated.

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum I do apologize if my tone appeared to be intimidating. By any means I didn't intend to make you feel like your opinion is insignificant. I'm sorry that I made you feel that way. I really feel your desire to make things nicer and support that.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`precondition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1540960-precondition) instead of `guard`:

```
func test() {
    precondition(yourCondition, "This is an error message")
    //rest of your function
}
```

If `yourCondition` is false, the scope is going to be exited and the error message will be printed.

Comment: I did not know about `precondition()`, it is very nice, thank you @Carpsen90

Comment: On occasion @Carpsen90, this will present a better solution than inokey's below, but I did promise him my accepted answer. If I could I would accept them both as I feel they both have their place.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to produce some output or show message on false condition or on nil value, before return in guard.
Below is my thinking:

```
func checkForNil(value: Any?) -> Any?
    {
        if value == nil
        {
            //showMessage("Nil value...")
            print("nil value")
        }
        return value
    }
```

you can use this as below:

```
guard let obj = self.checkForNil(value: objLoggedInUser) else { return}
```

Comment: This is a cute solution @Hardik-Darji, thank you, but as I have already promised my accepted answer to inokey above (on one caveat) I'm afraid I won't be accepting it.

Comment: Thank you @JosephBeuys'Mum
if you can upvote, will be gr8 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`closures`** to get it working, i.e.

```
func func1(handler: ((String)->())) {
    let condition = (2 == 2)
    guard condition == true else {
        handler("condition was false")
        return
    }
}

func1 { (reason) in
    print(reason)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input @PGDev but this seems worse than simply print()ing and returning.

Comment: You asked for the returning solution right? Printing is just a way of using that reason.